# Giving different outputs to multiple objects of same class

Tags: java, class, oop

I'm programming [Micro Space Empire](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/99698/micro-space-empire) in java for a college project, and I've just reached a point whereI'm having some issues I've had as well in a different Object Oriented Programming class, though in C++.

The game itself has these cards called "Events" which can be separated in about 4 or 5 categories and each has it's own outcome. Some give metal or wealth, some start an invasion in one of your empire's Planets, etc.

I've put everything as it's own class, so Events are a class, Systems (how planets are refered to) are a class, the game logic is itself a class, etc

The point here: how can I build a class Events which can be as generic as possible and allow for these different types of outcome?
Or, in other words, could anyone give me ideas on how to organize this in a way that would be as clean and as generic, yet efficient as possible?

The goal would be to keep the code for the result inside each individual Event object so as to avoid having to do anything related to the events or as little as possible "outside", i.e. on the the calling class.

I remember in that other C++ class I ended screwing up a bit and being forced to make a GIANT list of if-else's which i know could have been avoided, so I would really love to NOT have to use:

```
    if(eventObject.getType() == "Invasion")
        attempt to conquer selected system
    else if(eventObject.getType() == "Strike")
        no resources next turn
    else if
    else if
    else
    (...)
```

As I was told by a teacher this is a real C-like approach to things, and really goes against OOP principles.

I really like Object Oriented Programming, and I can handle very well with polymorphism and inheritance and so on, but these little things confuse me more than they should.

Any help with be greatly appreciated, I'm sure there's an obvious solution that I'm just not seeing.

Comment: Make Event abstract, add an abstract method `outcome()` to Event, create a subclass of Event for each type of event, each providing its own `outcome()` method implementation, doing the right think for that type of Event. In short, use polymorphism, which is what OO is all about :-)

Comment: No! Event should never produce or process something. Event should only carry information, that infuences behaviour of other part of a system.

Comment: @DenisKokorin just because something is named Event doesn't mean that it is exactly what you assume an Event is. The class could be named Card.

Comment: see this post maybe it can be helpful [How to use polymorphism to make list with different types in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55861318/how-to-use-polymorphism-to-make-list-with-different-types-in-java)