# Java - List with different object type

Tags: java, arrays

I have a Parent class. I made an array of 3 parent objects. I also have a child class. Is it possible that I can have 1 of those 3 array elements be a child object?

```
private ParentClass[] a = new ParentClass[3]

ParentClass a[] = {
     new ParentClass("0"),
     new ParentClass("1"),
     new ChildClass("2")
};
```

This works fine. But I'm wondering, is this the correct way of doing it or is there any easier/cleaner way?

New to java btw from C.

Comment: what happened when you tried it?

Comment: After running the above code, please don't post *I ran that particular code and it worked* question.

Comment: @roundAbout What do you mean?

Comment: @Reimeus Didn't get any errors. Just wondering, is this the right/best way of doing it? Java has so many new data types that I'm getting used to (coming from a C background).

Comment: Yes, it's the correct way. You'd use a `Collection` (like `List`) instead of arrays 99% of the time though.

Comment: @daniu Thank you. In my case, the number of elements in the array are fixed and known from the start. Is it still worth switching to a List?

Comment: What makes you think that there may be a _easier/cleaner way_ ? Remember that Java is object-oriented whereas C is not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build list with different types and call its elelment methods in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55861318/how-to-build-list-with-different-types-and-call-its-elelment-methods-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you can do the following, List.of comes with Java 9. The returned list is immutable, immutable objects are very nice in a lot cases. Also in Java, we do `Interface instance = new ImplementationClass()`, for example `List<Class> = new ArrayList<>()`, ArrayList implements List interface

`List<ParentClass> list = List.of(
     new ParentClass("0"),
     new ParentClass("1"),
     new ChildClass("2")
);`

Comment: Prior Java has `Arrays.asList(...) `.